# Time Series Classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, classification

you can access the data set at this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Hd-26lI95ZeVU5cDY0ZU5MTWs/view?usp=sharing

My Task is to predict the price movement of a sector fund. How much it goes up or down doesn't really matter, I only want to know whether it's going up or down. So I define it as a classification problem.

Since this data set is a time-series data, I met many problems. I have read articles about these problems like I can't use k-fold cross validation since this is time series data. You can't ignore the order of the data.

my code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.svm import SVCenter code here

lag1 = pd.read_csv(#local file path, parse_dates=['Date']) 

#Trend : if price going up: ture, otherwise false
lag1['Trend'] = lag1.XLF > lag1.XLF.shift()
train_size = round(len(lag1)*0.50)
train = lag1[0:train_size]
test = lag1[train_size:]

variable_to_use=    ['rGDP','interest_rate','private_auto_insurance','M2_money_supply','VXX']
y_train = train['Trend']
X_train = train[variable_to_use]
y_test = test['Trend']
X_test = test[variable_to_use]

#SVM  Lag1

this_C = 1.0
clf = SVC(kernel = 'linear', C=this_C).fit(X_train, y_train)
print('XLF Lag1 dataset')
print('Accuracy of Linear SVC classifier on training set: {:.2f}'
 .format(clf.score(X_train, y_train)))
print('Accuracy of Linear SVC classifier on test set: {:.2f}'
 .format(clf.score(X_test, y_test)))

#Check prediction results
clf.predict(X_test)
```

First of all, is my method right here : first generating a column of true and false? I am afraid the machine can't understand this column if I simply feed this column to it. Should I first perform a regression then compare the numeric result to generate a list of going up or down?

The accuracy on training set is very low at : 0.58  I am getting an array with all trues with clf.predict(X_test) which I don't know why I would get all trues.

And I don't know whether the resulting accuracy is calculated in which way: for example, I think my current accuracy only counts the number of true and false but ignoring the order of them? Since this is time-series data, ignoring the order is not right and gives me no information about predicting price movement. Let's say I have 40 examples in test set, and I got 20 Tures I would get 50% accuracy. But I guess the trues are no in the right position as it appears in the ground truth set. (Tell me if I am wrong)

I am also considering using Gradient Boosted Tree to do the classification, would it be better?

Answer (score 0):

Some preprocessing of this data would probably be helpful. Step one might go something like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('YOURLOCALFILEPATH',header=0)
#more code than your method but labels rows as 0 or 1 and easy to output to new file for later reference
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='d')
df = df.set_index('Date')
df['compare'] = df['XLF'].shift(-1)
df['Label'] np.where(df['XLF']>df['compare'), 1, 0)
df.drop('compare', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Step two can use one of sklearn's [built in scalers, such as the MinMax scaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html), to preprocess the data by scaling your feature inputs before feeding it into your model.